# I need a handler for render_complete but with OpenGL render

Tags: python, rendering, opengl

Is there a handler to execute a function after an OpenGL render (after the whole animation is rendered).

Because this script

```
import bpy

def end_rendering(dummy):
    print("I'm doing something")
    bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(end_rendering)

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(end_rendering)
bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT',animation=True)
```

works and prints `I'm doing something` after the animation is rendered, but this:

```
import bpy

def end_rendering(dummy):
    print("I'm doing something")
    bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(end_rendering)

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(end_rendering)
bpy.ops.render.opengl('INVOKE_DEFAULT',animation=True)
```

does nothing.

Is there a specific handler like "opengl_render_complete" or something? Anyway, is there a way to manage this and execute a function after an animation (called with 'INVOKE_DEFAULT') is rendered with opengl in python?

Comment: Can't find one, see yourself: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=handlers#module-bpy.app.handlers

Comment: Yeah, I checked it but I wander if there is another way to manage that.